# Is there any maximal 1-planar or 2-planar graph that is not 3-connected

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, graph-drawing

A graph is $k$-planar if it can be drawn in the plane so that each edge is crossed at most $k$ times. A $k$-planar graph $G$ is maximal if $G+uv$ is not $k$-planar for any non-adjacent vertices $u,v\in V(G)$.

- Is there any maximal $1$-planar graph that is not $3$-connected ?
- Is there any maximal $2$-planar graph that is not $3$-connected ?

I believe those examples exist but didn't find any references mentioned this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: non 3-connected maximal 1-planar graph]

This is a non-3-connected 1-planar example...

Answer (score 1):

The paper [On Properties of Maximal 1-planar Graphs](https://doi.org/10.7151/dmgt.1639) by Dávid Hudák, Tomáš Madaras and Yusuke Suzuki describes the construction of maximal 1-planar graphs with minimum degree 2 and with (relatively) small number of edges, namely, (8/3)*(n-2) (which is far less than the number of edges of a maximal n-vertex planar graph).