# A confusion about the proof of maximal 1-plane graph being $2$-connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-drawing

It is well known that every maximal planar graph with at least 4 vertices is 3-connected. But for maximal 1-planar graphs we cannot  ensure the high connectivity. (See [is-there-any-maximal-1-planar-or-2-planar-graph-that-is-not-3-connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365095/is-there-any-maximal-1-planar-or-2-planar-graph-that-is-not-3-connected?rq=1))

> A $1$*-planar graph* is a graph that can be drawn such that every
> edge has at most one crossing. A graph together with a 1-planar
> drawing is called *1-plane*. A graph is *maximal 1-plane* if we cannot
> add any edge from the complement so that the resulting graph is
> 1-plane and simple.
>
> We call the crossing-free edges *red edges*, and call the edges that
> are crossed *blue edges*. The *red graph* $G_R$ of $G$ is the subgraph
> induced by the red edges.

The following literature proves that any maximal 1-plane graph is 2-connected. (In fact, the authors prove a stronger result: A subgraph formed by all non-crossing edges is spanning and $2$-connected. But from the proof, the authors prove that maximal 1-plane graphs  are $2$-connected first, and then prove the stronger result.)

- Eades, P., Hong, S., Kato, N., Liotta, G., Schweitzer, P., Suzuki, Y.: A linear time algorithmfor testing maximal 1-planarity of graphs with a rotation system. Theoret. Comput. Sci. 513, 65–76 (2013) [doi.org/10.1016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2013.09.029)

I'm confused by the part that deals with proving that a maxmal 1-plane graph is 2-connected (see the proof for details in Theorem 3).

**Theorem 3.** In a maximal 1-planar embedding $ξ(G)$ of a graph $G$ with at least $3$ vertices, the red graph $G_R$ is biconnected and spans all vertices.

> (a). Prove that $G_R$  spans all vertices.
>
> (b). **The confusing proof part**. To prove biconnectivity, we first show that $G$ is biconnected. Lemma 1 implies that each face has two real vertices.
> By Lemma 2, if two real vertices are adjacent to the same virtual vertex in $G_P$ then there are two vertex-disjoint paths between the two real vertices. Thus to show biconnectivity of $G$, it suffices to show the following: If $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are real
> vertices that, ignoring virtual vertices, appear consecutively in this order on a face of the planarization $G_P$ of $G$, then there
> is a path from $v_1$ to $v_3$ that avoids $v_2$. This is clear, since $v_1$ and $v_3$ are incident with the same face, and therefore are adjacent since $G$ is maximal.
>
> (c). $G_R$ is 2-connected.

We know that **a graph is $2$-connected if and only if  there are at least $2$ vertex-disjoint paths between every pair of vertices.**

In the above proof I feel that the author has adopted the idea. **But I do not see that the two vertices considered by the author are *arbitrary*. Note that in the proof the two vertices chosen lie in a face in the 1-planar embedding $ξ(G)$. That is to say, why the authors say:**

> Thus to show biconnectivity of $G$, it suffices to show the following: If $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are real
> vertices that, ignoring virtual vertices, appear consecutively in this order on a face of the planarization $G_P$ of $G$, then there
> is a path from $v_1$ to $v_3$ that avoids $v_2$.

Why are two vertices that do not lie in the same face (may contains crossing point)  not considered?

---

PS:
As shown in the figure, the authors consider two vertices that lie in the same face. Indeed, there are two vertex-disjoint paths between two vertices in the case ($v_1$ and $v_2$; $v_1$ and $v_3$).
[image]

**Lemma 1.** Let ξ(G) be a 1-planar embedding of a 1-planar graph $G$ on at least $2$ vertices, and $G_P$ be the planarization of $G$. Each face
$f$ of $G_P$ has at least two real vertices.

**Lemma 2.** Let $G$ be a maximal 1-plane graph. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are consecutive neighbors of a virtual vertex $w$ in the planarization $G_P$
of $G$, then there are two internally vertex-disjoint red paths (that is, paths consisting of red edges) from $v_1$ to $v_2$.